# Why am I getting Error 1327 - Invalid Drive when installing Office 2010?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I am trying to install Office 2010 and I am getting this error:

[image: Error 1327.Invalid Drive: H:]

This is a valid drive on my machine (it's a network shared drive) so I don't see why it is saying that this is an invalid drive. I actually don't understand what it's trying to do on this drive as I'm doing a local install.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked *[You receive a "Error 1327. Invalid Drive... " error message when you install Office 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873301)* yet?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have permission to install an application on that network drive.  The advice in the link that slhck still applies to Office 2010.

Comment: @Ramhound - I am not trying to install on that drive.  It shows me installing to C:\Program Files

Comment: @leora - WHy does it say `H:\` then?

Comment: @Ramhound - I have no idea . . maybe there is some files that it installs on your personal folders but the install path for the app is definately C:\Program Files . . anyway, i figured out the issue, see below

Answer (score 1):

The link in the comment got to the right answer.  I was running the install as administrator which didn't have the drive mapped so i had to

1. Run cmd as administrator
2. net use H: //[drivename]
3. run install as administrator